# How can i draw any line on surfaceview which is already rendering Camera Preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas, surfaceview

When I try below statement in `SurfaceChanged` override method I get an exception.

```
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
```

> Exception - IllegalStateException

My Requirement: I need to do this using 1 `SurfaceView`, Not by taking `SurfaceView` in other layouts. My purpose is to live stream `SurfaceView` preview with a line drawn on it using canvas.

Comment: add surface view in other layout and then draw canvas in that parent layout.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Thanks but My Requirement is like this - I need to do this using 1 surfaceview, Not by taking surfaceview in other layout. My purpose is to Live stream surfaceview preview with line drawn on it using canvas.

Comment: you have to add parent layout if adding your canvas on your surface view than it will update every time

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Can you please share me layout structure. So i can have clear idea what you mean to say. Thanks

Comment: @Parmit check my answer it will work because i had face same issue with surface view

Answer (score 0):

add your surface view in one of any parent layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I had created box to overlay camera

```
public class Box extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    Box(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // Override the onDraw() Method
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        //center
        int x0 = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        int y0 = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        int dx = (int) (canvas.getWidth() / 2.5);
        int dy = (int) (canvas.getHeight() / 2.9);
        //draw guide box
        canvas.drawRect(x0 - dx, y0 - dy, x0 + dx, y0 + dy, paint);
    }
}
```

Now adding this box to parent layout so it can be not updating my surface

```
        Box box = new Box(this);
        relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.control);
        relativeLayout.addView(box, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: In above snippet, If i record video or stream video from surfaceview, It will not display box which is drawn because both view's are separate. Live streams with Wowza GoCoder Which takes surfaceholder to stream or broadcast live preview. So i need camera & box in same surfaceview so that both can be streamed live.

Comment: i had just given example here you can add your logic